# Not able to use MAVEN command

Tags: java, maven

I don't know what's the problem but I am not able to use a maven for my projects.

[image]

This is the output of the command that means all the setup for maven is done properly but dont know why performing tasks is leading to a BUILD FAILURE.

mvn.cmd
[image]

mvn clean

[image]

Comment: Show your project structure. Are you running mvn clean from the directory where pom.xml exist at the same level?

Comment: Where is your pom.xml located? Run from your project base directory

Comment: Also, mvn.cmd is not a valid command. mvn command should have lifecycles like - clean, compile and install.,etc. Ex: mvn compile

Answer (score 1):

You are in your main user folder `vipul`. The `clean` command is project specific, you need to be in the project path, a project which is configured for maven (has `pom.xml` file)

Answer (score 1):

The error says you don't have a `pom.xml` file, which means you're running the command in the wrong directory or you haven't got the project set up. This quick [Maven overview guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) will help you set up a project if you haven't already.